# PGFPlots - no markers in plot file

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to have no markers in a file plot (in other words, I want no dots in the picture, only the line itself), but the markers=none option does not seem to work, like it does in the normal plots.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xlabel={Frequency [nm]},
   ylabel={Absorbance},
   xmin=200, xmax=450,
   ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
   grid style=dashed
]
\addplot file[marks=none,color=blue]{UV1.tex};
\addlegendentry{Sample 1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please pass the options to the plot, not to the table: `\addplot[marks=none,color=blue] file{UV1.tex};`. And please consider posting full codes that start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. BTW, it is a bit unusual to call data files `UV1.tex`, `.tex` files usually contain TeX code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, the marks=none option gives an error, but the plot will have no marks by default if I pass no option about it: `\addplot[color=blue] file{UV1.tex};`

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, it should be `mark=none`. Glad to hear you got what you wanted.